# How would I expand Least Square formulation algebraically?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, least-squares

I am struggling to derive this as I am still getting my head around matrix manipulation.

How would I simplify this least square algebraically i.e I am looking for $(a+b)^2 = a^2+2ab +b^2$ equivalent of this:
$$\Vert y - A(A^TA)^{-1} (\lambda+A^Ty)\Vert_2^2$$

where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{M\times N}$, $y \in \mathbb{R}^M$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}^N$ and $A$ is full Rank.

Edit: Correction $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}^N$, (previously $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$).

---

This problem is arising from a non-negative Least Squares problem, where I started with the Lagrangian:
$$ \min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^{N}} \Vert y-Ax \Vert_2^2 -\lambda^Tx$$
Whose Solution is: $$x^* = (A^TA)^{-1} (\lambda+ A^Ty)$$
Plugging this back into the Lagrangian to find the dual results an expression a part of which is the expression in my question. Just to give background.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you mean $y - A(A^TA)^{-1}(\lambda I + A^T y)$, we can rewrite it as
$$Iy - A(A^TA)^{-1}(\lambda I + A^T y) = (I-A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T)y - \lambda A(A^TA)^{-1} = My -N$$

Now we have $$\|My-N\|_2^2$$ which in some sense is a standard form we can work with

---

The only difference with the knowledge $\lambda$ is a matrix, let us call it $\Lambda$ instead, will be that we need to make sure we respect that matrix multiplication is not commutative, so when multiplying together we get $$A(A^TA)^{-1}\Lambda$$ with $\Lambda$ to the right so the expression becomes

$$(I-A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T)y - A(A^TA)^{-1}\Lambda$$

It will still be on the same form $My-N$, just that the $N$ matrix is slightly different.

Comment: I am so sorry, I just corrected a minute ago that $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}^N$ and is not a scalar. Sorry if it made you waste your time. I have fixed it, I would really appreciate it if you could look at it again (if you have the time.)

Comment: This problem is arising from a non-negative Least Squares problem, where I started with the Lagrangian: $\Vert y - Ax \Vert_2^2 - \lambda^T x$, whose solution is: $x^* = (A^TA)^{-1} (\lambda + A^T y)$. Plugging this back into the Lagrangian to find the dual results an expression a part of which is the expression in my question. Just to give background.

Comment: I am not sure if these are equivalent, but my problem had the expression: $$A(A^TA)^{-1} (\lambda+A^Ty)$$, whereas you started with $$A(A^TA)^{-1} A^{-1} (\lambda+A^Ty)$$. i.e. with an extra $A^{-1}$
Is this a typo? If this is correct, how did you go from one to another?

Comment: Yep you are correct. An elf seems to have snuck in an extra $A$ before the inverse sign. I think I cleaned it out now, unless the elf modified something else while I was focused on fixing the last one.